# Define an order for string y-axis items

Tags: javascript, plotly

I have dataset that contains an enum value and a timestamp:

```js
var trace = {
  x: [1,2,3,4,5,6], // numbers for simplicity
  y: ['FOUR','TWO','THREE','FIVE','ONE','FOUR'],
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  type: 'scatter'
};
 Plotly.newPlot('graph', [trace]);
```

```css
div.plotly-notifier {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="graph"></div>
</body>
```

[image]

Plotly is adding the y-axis items as they come in, but I would like to have them ordered from ONE-FIVE.

I tried to feed data sorted by the enum, but then the data points go back and forth because the order matters for the timeline.

I thought about adding fake points in the beginning with all enum values in order, but I obviously don't want them to be visible.

Are there any tricks I can try?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please include a sample of your dataset and a code snippet?

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to put the numeric values in y and a lookup table into the layout.

```js
var trace = {
  x: {
        tickmode: 'array',
        tickvals: [1,2,3,4,5,6]
},
  y: [4,2,3,5,1,4],
  mode: 'lines+markers',
  type: 'scatter'
};
var layout = {
  yaxis: {
    tickvals: [1,2,3,4,5],
    ticktext: ['ONE', 'TWO', 'THREE', 'FOUR', 'FIVE'],
  }
};
Plotly.newPlot('graph', [trace], layout);
```

```css
div.plotly-notifier {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="graph"></div>
</body>
```